# SQL Server Session State using "blue/green" deployment. Issue with different paths

Tags: iis, session

I've been working on trying to get a [blue/green deployment architecture](https://kevinareed.com/2015/11/07/how-to-deploy-anything-in-iis-with-zero-downtime-on-a-single-server/) setup on a windows 2016 server. But just ran into a brick wall because since these 2 web farm "servers" are actually not separate servers, but reside on the same server, they can't have the same path.

From: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/ms178586(v=vs.100)

> The path for the ASP.NET application in the IIS metabase must be identical on all Web servers that share session state in the SQL Server database. For information on steps to resolve the issue when application paths differ between servers, see article 325056, "PRB: Session State Is Lost in Web Farm If You Use SqlServer or StateServer Session Mode," in the Microsoft Knowledge Base at http://support.microsoft.com.

And from: https://mskb.pkisolutions.com/kb/325056

> To maintain session state across different Web servers in the Web farm, the application path of the Web site (for example, \LM\W3SVC\2) in the Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) metabase must be the same for all of the Web servers in the Web farm. The case also needs to be the same because the application path is case-sensitive.

So is there any work around to running SQL Server Session State when not using the same website path as both websites in the farm are on the same server and hence can't share the same path name?